# Node-sqlite3: Efficiently select rows by various ids, in a single query

Tags: node.js, typescript, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I'd like to write a wrapper function `function select(db: any, ids: number[]): Cat[]` that returns an array of `Cat` rows fetched from the DB by ID. The function should return the entire array of rows.

Below is one approach I've written. Instead of calling `db.each` on every ID in a for-loop as I do below, is it possible to pass my entire `ids: number[]` array as a parameter to a `db.all` / `db.each` query function?

```js
// dbmethods.ts

async function select(db: any, ids: number[]): Promise<Cat[]> {
  let query = "SELECT * FROM cats_table WHERE id = ?;";
  let cats_back: Cat[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    let cat: Promise<Cat> = new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
      await db.get(query, ids[i], (err: Error, row: any) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          let cat: Cat = {
            index: row.id,
            cat_type: row.cat_type,
            health: row.health,
            num_paws: row.num_paws
          };

          resolve(cat);
        }
      });
    });

    cats_back.push(await cat);
  }

  return cats_back;
}
```

and

```js
// index.ts

let ids = create_many_ids(10_000); // returns an array of unique ordered ints between 0 and 10K
let res = await select(db, ids);
console.log(res); // successfully prints my cats
```

Benchmarks on my `select` function above suggest that it takes 300ms to select 10_000 rows by ID. It seems to me that's a little long; 10K rows shouldn't take that long for sqlite's select by id functionality... How can I be more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM cats_table WHERE id IN (SELECT value FROM json_each(?));
```

The query parameter is a string representing a JSON array of ids, e.g., '[1, 2, 4]'

See this [tutorial](https://pchemguy.gitlab.io/SQLite-SQL-Tutorial/patterns/json-sql-input) for further details